Show that the supremum of a family of continuous functions is lower semicontinuous.

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Consider a family $\{f_i \mid i \in I\}$ of continuous functions $f_i : X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}.$ Define $M : X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by $M(x) = \text{sup}\{f_{i}(x) \mid i \in I\}.$ Show that $M$ is lower semicontinuous.

I've already solved this problem by using the fact $M^{-1}(r, \infty)$ is open for every $r \in \mathbb{R}.$ since it is equal to $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in M^{-1}(r, \infty)} f_x^{-1}(r, \infty)$ where  $f_x(x) \gt r,$ so it's not that I can't solve this problem at all, but I want to find a more slick proof for this by using the fact that if $\mathcal{T}_{\epsilon}^{\prime}$ is the topology induced by the basis $\mathcal{B}^{\prime} = \{ (r, \infty) \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{\epsilon}$ is the standard euclidean topology then $M$ is lower semicontinuous over $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{\epsilon})$ if and only if $M$ is continuous over $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{\epsilon}^{\prime}).$
Here is where I run into a problem. I know that when $M$ is the supremum of an arbitrary family of continuous functions, it's not necessary that $M$
be continuous itself. But given that $f_i$ is continuous over the extended real line, if I could somehow show that continuity over the extended real line instead of the real line can result in continuity of the supremum in this case, I'd be done. But I don't know how to go about this. Any hints?
